# Postgresql load file csv with new line characters

Tags: postgresql, csv, newline

I'm new to this very interesting blog. This is my problem: I have to load a csv file with three columns (field1, field2 and field3), in a postgresql table.
In the string contained in the field1 column there are new line characters.
I use sql statements:

```
COPY test (regexp_replace (field1,, E '[\\n\\r] +', '', 'g'),
field2, field3)
from 'D:\zzz\aaa20.csv' WITH DELIMITER '|';
```

but it reports me an error.

How can I remove new line characters?

Comment: What error does it report?

Comment: This is the error:    Syntax error at or at "("   -  SQL state: 42601   -  Character:180

Answer (score 1):

If the newlines are properly escaped by quoting the value, this should not be a problem.

If your data are corrupted CSV files with unescaped newlines, you will have to do some pre-processing.  If you are willing to give the database user permission to execute programs on the database server, you could use

```
COPY mytable FROM PROGRAM 'demangle D:\zzz\aaa20.csv' (FORMAT 'csv');
```

Here, `demangle` is a program or script that reads the file, fixes the data and outputs them to standard output.  Since you are on Windows, you probably don't have access to tools like `sed` and `awk` that can be used for such purposes, and you may have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is syntax of `COPY` command:

```
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
FROM { 'filename' | STDIN }
[ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
```

You can only add optional list of column names, and not function calls (`regexp_replace` in your case) or some other complex constructions.

You can create some temporal table import data into it and than copy data in your table using ordinal `INSERT...SELECT` query.